# Check for symbolic link

Tags: unix, symlink, shell

I have a symbolic link a.c in my home directory to another file in the same directory.

a.c -> b.c

I know how to check a.c is a symbolic link using the shell script

```
if [ -L /home/nit/a.c ] ; then
    echo "a.c is a symbolic link"
fi
```

But my question is how to write a shell script to check whether a.c is a symbolic link specifically to b.c ?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `readlink`;

```
[~]> ln -s foo bar
[~]> readlink bar 
foo
```

Comment: So, `if [[ -L a.c ]] && [[ "$(readlink a.c)" = "b.c" ]]; then echo "a.c is a link to b.c"; fi`

Answer (score 6):

You could also do `ls -F filename.txt`
which returns  `filename.txt@` if it is a symbolic link.